# I'm hiding site with index.htm but now I can't get to index.php

Tags: migration, maintenance

I am trying to work on a new Wordpress-site on the web. I am 'hiding' the site by putting up index.htm in the home-directory so that visiters see this html with some text about 'maintenance' and not the Wordpress-site.

But now if I go to www.example.com/index.php it redirects to www.example.com/ and shows the index.htm. I can't preview what I am doing in the admin.

Is there anyway I can change Wordpress-settings so it won't redirect /index.php to /?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use FileZilla to rename `index.htm` to something else and then visit. There is no setting in WP to handle this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I know now I don't need to look into Wordpress-settings.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution to your problem would be to use a maintenance mode plugin. These plugins will show a splash page to your visitors, but allow administrators full access to the site.

You can find these plugins in the Plugin Repository, for example:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/maintenance-mode/

Comment: Also [Coming soon](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/) and [Password Protect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/password-protect-wordpress/) have worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Under settings in WordPress you can decide where you want your WordPress site displayed.

Under Settings->Site address (URL), for example if you decide to display your site in a subfolder like this http://example.com/temp/

You just gotta create a folder called "temp" place your index.php file in there and edit it.

Change this line:

require('./wp-blog-header.php');

to

require('../wp-blog-header.php');

Answer (score 0):

Change site URL because wordpress redirects to it automatically we can't do it normally use default but it happens in this type of conditions.